# Catalog Price Rule will not activate after 1.8.1.0 upgrade

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0, upgrade, catalog-price-rules

After upgrading Magento from 1.7.1.0 to 1.8.1.0 I have created a new catalog category price rule > save & apply > flushed cache = No Change to the category?

I see that this has already been raised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19857309/magento-1-8-0-0-promotion-catalog-price-rules-does-not-work-when-condition-i) but this doesn't not work for me.

Comment: You mentioned that you created the price rule after upgrade. Have you tried it before? Do you have Magento cron jobs set up?

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks for response. No I had not tried this before, I just assumed it was an upgrade problem after looking at some others threads. I am relatively new to Magento and have no idea on cron jobs? I will make a search now.

Comment: Does the cronjob not just action the same as the save & apply button function? I just looked in my cpanel and there is a cronjob set up for 30 min, command: public_html/cron.php